# DXA static content folder

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

I am trying to use some static css files from file system path like ~/design/css/imagename. In trace log it seems dxa is searching these files in broker. Can anyone suggest if we need to configure this path as static content path, so that IIS caching or DXA caching can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using .NET or Java.

For .NET, when you have a specific directory that includes static files (not published by the CMS), you can always exclude that folder from any mvc routing via the global.asax via

```
routes.IgnoreRoute(cidUrlPath + "/{*pathInfo}");
```

(See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Global.asax.cs for some examples.)

If you are using Java, I believe you should use a different approach. Here, you can put any of your static images or files in a jar file, and add a resource handler in your webapp, like explained here

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources